# [NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance when using nsmutabledictionery

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    NSString *dateString;
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a"];
    dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [formatter release];

    appDelegate.myCallLogDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [appDelegate.myCallLogDict setObject:phoneNo forKey:@"CallLogPhoneNoKey"];
    [appDelegate.myCallLogDict setObject:dateString forKey:@"CallLogTimeStampKey"];
```

I have stored phone no and time into an nsmutabledictionery and i want to access that dictionery value as like below into the -

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[appDelegate.myCallLogDict objectForKey:@"CallLogTimeStampKey" ]objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.text = [[appDelegate.myCallLogDict objectForKey:@"CallLogPhoneNoKey"] objectAtIndex:row];
```

when i run the above code i get the below error

Please help me up

```
-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b227e0
2011-12-15 10:06:09.050 MyDialer[1090:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b227e0'
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: did you make property of myCallLogDict and synthesis it in appappDelegate?

Comment: yes i did it in the app delegate

Comment: "-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector" means that you attempted to perform an `objectAtIndex:` operation on an NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to save your key data in an array and then use the `objectAtIndex` on that array.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [appDelegate.myCallLogDict objectForKey:@"CallLogTimeStampKey"];
cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.myCallLogDict objectForKey:@"CallLogPhoneNoKey"];
```

you don't need to use objectAtIndex as you are getting single string by

```
[appDelegate.myCallLogDict objectForKey:@"CallLogPhoneNoKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting your dictionary to contain an array of strings for the key CallLogTimeStampKey, but you inserted just a single string.

Comment: @user198725878 -- Insert NSLogs, pls, and figure it out yourself.

Comment: `... setObject:dateString ...` inserts a single string. `... objectForKey:@"CallLogPhoneNoKey"] objectAtIndex:row]` expects the contents of the dictionary to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was the following problem:

1. there is a property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *selectedCell;`
2. which synthezided as `@synthesize selectedCell = _selectedCell;`
3. with a getter

   - (NSIndexPath *)selectedCell
     {
     if (!_selectedCell) {
         _selectedCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedImageNumber inSection:kTexturesListSection];
     }
     return _selectedCell;
     }
4. and then some where in the code the call self.selectedCell.row caused crash

After getter has been changed to

- (NSIndexPath *)selectedCell
  {
  if (!_selectedCell) {
      _selectedCell = [[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedImageNumber inSection:kTexturesListSection] retain];
  }
  return _selectedCell;
  }

a bug disappeared. The bug has been noticed on iOS 5 only.